# Import csv file in PostgreSQL 15

Tags: postgresql

I tried it in postgreSQL 15 and 16. But, the same error I get. Is there anyone can help me with this? Why is that? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: If the database is running on your machine, you can move the file somewhere it's accessible by postgres. If it's running elsewhere, [pgadmin has an Import/Export Data Dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/import_export_data.html) that basically wraps `psql \copy` suggested by the error message - you can use that for local imports as well. And again: don't post code and error messages as pictures. Copy and paste them into your question as text. Use `pgadmin` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've been sitting for hours thinking why it gives me permission denied. I found out that it is all about the grant privileges in Postgres in which it's denying the import of it. So, I did check the properties of the csv. Edit it of who can use it and it solved my problem. But, is it reliable and convenient to do it or should I learn to use the "GRANT SELECT ON table_name to user_name;”. Do I need to include "grant" in every query I make to import csv files?

Comment: By the way, I do not understand why this community is very strict when it comes to images. For me, it would be best to include an image because those audience that wanted to help will be able to understand the real problem and be able to provide the right answer or close to the right answer to solve the issue. So I suggest to the creator/ developer of this community to get rid of the "adding images option".

Comment: The issue is not with permissions to objects within Postges, you would have gotten a different error message.  The issue is that the user that the Postgres server is running as did not have permissions for the CSV file. `GRANT SELECT ON ...` is for a different issue that can be solved by logging in as a user with sufficient privileges.

Comment: Images are frowned on because: 1) They often contain extraneous information that needs to be waded through to get to the point 2) Many times they are in the form of links to third party sites that go dead 3) Responders to the question are not able to copy and paste text and use the information contained within. to answer the question. Read [Ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information on this as well as other helpful tips.

Comment: There are times when images convey important information that text alone is unable to adequately convey; however, the image in this post is not such a case. Even if the image does provide useful information beyond the text alone, it would be preferable to also include the textual information as text.

Comment: See [Why not  upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database server is probably running locally on the same machine as the .csv file you're trying to COPY from. Rather than focus on why COPY isn't working, let's try an alternative approach which should achieve the result you probably want in this case:

- In the pgAdmin tree view, right-click your table object nyc_airlines
- From the right-click menu, select Import/Export data...
- Ensure the Import/Export switch is set to Import
- Enter/select your Filename
- Switch to the Options tab, and ensure the Header switch is set to True and Delimiter is set to ,
- Adjust any other settings as required to suit your particular .csv
- Click OK
- If it fails, check the error messages via the Processes interface in pgAdmin, return to the Import/Export interface to adjust any settings as required for your situation and try again

As Zegarek commented, this should achieve what you're after using psql \copy instead of the server-side COPY, which should circumvent the issue you're encountering with visibility of the .csv file to the postgres server